# Wordpress admin_init in custom plugin on a custom function throws fatal error

Tags: php, wordpress

A bit weird but really is ask-able question. I am creating a custom QuickBook Oauth plugin. I activated the plugin via admin dashboard but the functions defined in the plugin are not being loaded on do_action function but rather throws a fatal error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_rtl() in D:\xamp\htdocs\projectmanager\wp-includes\general-template.php on line 2616
```

Here's my plugin code

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Oauth Quick Book
 * Plugin URI: https://www.test.com
 * Description: Authenticate to QuickBook and send/receives data
 * Version: 0.1.0
 * Author: Myname here
 * Author Uri: https://www.mysitehere.com
 * License: GPL-2.0+
 */
do_action('admin_init', 'authenticate');
function authenticate() {
            var_dump($_GET);exit;
        if(isset($_GET['app_token']))
        {
            if(current_user_can('cpm_super_admin'))
            {
                $app_token = $_GET['app_token'];
                $oauth_consumer_key = $_GET['consumer_key'];
                $oauth_consumer_secret = $_GET['consumer_secret'];
                $token = $_GET['app_token'];

                if(isset($oauth_consumer_secret) && $oauth_consumer_secret != null && $oauth_consumer_key != null && $app_token != null) 
                {

                    if ( ! add_post_meta( 1000011, 'oauth_request_token', $oauth_consumer_key, true ) ) { 
                       update_post_meta ( 1000011, 'oauth_request_token', $oauth_consumer_key );
                    }

                    if ( ! add_post_meta( 1000012, 'app_token', $token , true ) ) { 
                       update_post_meta ( 1000012, 'app_token', $token  );
                    }

                    if ( ! add_post_meta( 1000013, 'oauth_request_token_secret', $oauth_consumer_secret, true ) ) { 
                       update_post_meta ( 1000013, 'oauth_request_token_secret', $oauth_consumer_secret );
                    }

                    require_once (plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'quickbooks-php/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/index.php');
                } else
                {
                    // require_once (plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'quickbooks-php/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/index.php');
                }
            }
        }
}
```

When I remove the do_action function then it does not throw any error.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use [`do_action`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action) as it ***execute*** the action. Use instead [`add_action`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) to attach your function to the `admin_init` action:

```
add_action('admin_init', 'authenticate');
```

That way it will be called at the right time, on admin initialization, so this hook ([`admin_init`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_init)) will be triggered only when an user access admin area. If you want your function to execute on every page load, use the [`init`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init) hook or if you want it to execute only when an user log in, use the [`wp_login`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login) hook.

Comment: I did try using add_action with admin_init hook but that still did not work and I used `after_setup_theme`

Comment: Well the `admin_init` did not work for me but everything else seems fine so am going ahead to accept it as an answer I would also be thankful if you update your answer and clearify it a bit that where `admin_init` should work or not?

Comment: I updated my answer to add details about the hooks. I suggest to take a look to the [action reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/) to pick the hook you need to use.